# Why does the video area of a TMediaplayercontrol appear above all standard controls on Firemonkey Android?

Tags: android, delphi, media-player, firemonkey

If I play files with the TMediaplayer component on an android device the TMediaplayer control is shown above other standard controls and the user can not access the control buttons(play , pause , next ,....).
Why does this happen?
How to show a video in a limited panel?

Comment: I can't find the website again but I have read somewhere that when you play videos on android they are always played in full screen on the native android surface. Controlling of video playback should be done by default android controlls. I haven't tested this out since I don't own android device.